# Setting a static IP to docker container using LXC driver

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, docker, lxc

I installed docker to my ubuntu 14.04 laptop. I pulled docker registry image from the central registry. To fix IP address of the container to a static value, I first changed my `/etc/defaults/docker` and added `-e lxc` to `DOCKER_OPTS` variable.

Then to run my local registry I used the following command;

```
docker run \
-i -t -h myreg  \
--net="none" \
--lxc-conf="lxc.network.hwaddr=91:21:de:b0:6b:61" \
--lxc-conf="lxc.network.type = veth" \
--lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv4 = 172.17.0.20/16" \
--lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 172.17.42.1"  \
--lxc-conf="lxc.network.link = docker0" \
--lxc-conf="lxc.network.name = eth0" \
--lxc-conf="lxc.network.flags = up" \
--name myreg \
-p 5000:5000 \
-d registry  \
/bin/bash
```

Then used `docker attach myreg` to access to the shell of the container. After installing net-tools package, I checked the IP address of it and see that it is 172.17.0.20 as expected. I tried to ping it from my host and it was replying.

The problem is that, when I checked the configuration of this container with `docker inspect myreg`, the NetworkSettings part of output was as the following

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "docker0",
    "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.8",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "PortMapping": null,
    "Ports": {
        "5000/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "5000"
            }
        ]
    }
```

It was showing 172.17.0.8 as the IP address of it.It is the value that should be assigned if I was not usign lxc driver. This is becoming a problem when I use `docker push` command to push a tagged image to this local registry. Because,`docker` is using this wrong IP to push image, and throws an error log as the following

```
de7e1cfc] +job push(127.0.0.1:5000/mongo)
2014/07/18 17:10:19 Can't forward traffic to backend tcp/172.17.0.8:5000: dial tcp  172.17.0.8:5000: no route to host
2014/07/18 17:10:22 Can't forward traffic to backend tcp/172.17.0.8:5000: dial tcp 172.17.0.8:5000: no route to host
```

What is the problem here? Or am I doing smt. wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Docker are you running? Docker 1.0 no longer uses LXC, they have replaced it with their own libcontainer. The LXC commands didn't work for me when following this blog - http://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/01/21/connecting-docker-containers-on-multiple-hosts/#_set_up

If you downgrade to 0.7 and follow the lxc process, it will work.

Comment: I am using Docker version 1.1.1, build bd609d2. As I explained in my question, LXC driver is working and I am able to give static IP to my container. Problem is that although I am using the given static IP to communicate with this container, docker adds another IP to inspect command output.